# mysql trigger to update row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to mysql and am trying to create a trigger. I want to take a newly inserted value from one table and want to update another table by subtracting this values from the value in that table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_updated
  AFTER INSERT ON ORDERdetails
  for EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE product_trial
      SET Quantity = Quantity-NEW.quantity
      where productid = new.ProductID;
  END
```

This gives SQL syntax error near line 6 (Update query) error 1064.
Kindly help.

Comment: I assume the duplicate **CREATE** statement was an error - please edit it out if it is. Also, could you please include the table layouts for your two tables? The output of the `DESCRIBE` command would be idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you don't need BEGIN-END because there is a single query executed in the for loop. If you remove them if solves the syntax error.

If you need to keep the BEGIN-END because your real life case is more complex, then you need to define a delimiter, as

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_updated AFTER INSERT ON ORDERdetails for EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE product_trial SET Quantity = Quantity-NEW.quantity where productid = new.ProductID;
END \\
```